# Windows Linux subsystem commands do nothing and fail silently

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've activated the Linux Subsystem in Windows and thought everything was working fine; I pulled down my dotfiles and vim config and everything seemed great - until I started trying to work.

To start, I wanted to set up a Foundation project - which meant I'd need node (npm), bower, and the foundation CLI.

I installed node successfully using apt-get but couldn't run npm so I installed it using apt-get as well - Then I successfully used npm to install the foundation-cli.

When I tried to run the `foundation new` command, though, it just fails silently or does nothing.

`node -v` yields the same results; nothing happens.
I checked my path and used `which` to confirm that node, npm, and foundation are all in my path (although, they are all in different directories in my path)

Is this a path issue? Permissions?

Here's my output for reference:

```
root@SC-ME-W10:~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
root@SC-ME-W10:~# which npm
/usr/bin/npm
root@SC-ME-W10:~# npm -v
1.3.10
root@SC-ME-W10:~# which node
/usr/sbin/node
root@SC-ME-W10:~# node -v
root@SC-ME-W10:~# which foundation
/usr/local/bin/foundation
root@SC-ME-W10:~# foundation -v
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd have issues getting `node` to work properly as well. I have had success installing it via nvm.
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Here's a set of instructions from memory in case it helps:

1. Uninstall currently installed versions of Node and npm.
2. `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash`
    as per https://github.com/creationix/nvm
3. Close and reopen `bash`.
4. nvm install 6 (or whichever version you're looking for)
5. Try to work w/ `npm` and `node` as you do normally.